# Unknown data format returned by firebase

Tags: json, firebase

While obtaining record from firebase in `appinventor`, data is returned in following format.

```
{ a=1 , b=2, c=3}
```

What is this format?  Is there anyway this format can be converted into a standard format like `JSON`.

P.S replacing `'=' with ':'` do not work either.